# Grails clean/ build tasks from ant

Tags: grails, ant

Is it possible to run

```
grails clean
grails build
```

ect

tasks from ant script?

Thanks!

Comment: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this [macro](http://cantina.co/2008/09/01/fitting-grails-into-an-ant-build-environment/). Though it gives pretty much what the [ANT exec](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) task would give you.